# Sharing variables between threads in Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I am trying to implement asynchronous gradient descent with TensorFlow using Python threads. In the main code, I define the graph, including a training operation, which gets a variable to keep count of the `global_step`:

```
with tf.variable_scope("scope_global_step") as scope_global_step:
    global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

If I print the name of `global_step` I get:

> scope_global_step/global_step:0

The main code also launches several threads to execute a `training` method:

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=training, args=(sess, train_op, loss, scope_global_step)) for i in xrange(NUM_TRAINING_THREADS)]
for t in threads: t.start()
```

I would like each thread to stop execution if the value of `global_step` is greater than or equal to `FLAGS.max_steps`. For that, I build the `training` method as it follows:

```
def training(sess, train_op, loss, scope_global_step):
    while (True):
         _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
         with tf.variable_scope(scope_global_step, reuse=True): 
            global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
            global_step = global_step.eval(session=sess)
            if global_step >= FLAGS.max_steps: break
```

This fails with the message:

> ValueError: Under-sharing: Variable scope_global_step/global_step does not exist, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

I can see that `:0` is added to the name of the variable when it is first created, and when I try to retrieve it, that suffix is not used. Why is this? 
If I manually add the suffix to the name of the variable when I try to retrieve it, it still claims the variable does not exist. Why does TensorFlow not find the variable? Shouldn't the variables automatically be shared among threads? I mean, all threads are running inside the same session, right?

And another question related to my `training` method: will `global_step.eval(session=sess)` execute the graph again, or will it just fetch the value assigned to `gloabl_step` after the execution of the `train_op` and `loss` operations? In general, what is the recommended way of fetching values from variables to be used inside Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Pass the `global_step` `tf.Variable` object that you created in the first code fragment as one of the training thread arguments, and call `sess.run(global_step)` on the passed-in variable.

As a general rule, your training loop (and especially a training loop in a separate thread) should not modify the graph. The `tf.variable_scope()` context manager and `tf.get_variable()` *can* modify the graph (even though they don't always), so you shouldn't use them in your training loop. The safest thing to do is to pass the `global_step` object (that you created in the first place) as one of the `args` tuple when you create the training threads. Then you can simply rewrite your training function as:

```
def training(sess, train_op, loss, global_step):
    while (True):
         _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
         current_step = sess.run(global_step)
         if current_step >= FLAGS.max_steps: break
```

To answer your other question, running `global_step.eval(session=sess)` or `sess.run(global_step)` only fetches the current value of the `global_step` variable, and doesn't re-execute the rest of your graph. This is the recommended way to fetch `tf.Variable` values for use in Python code.

Comment: Thanks @mrry. Your solution is certainly cleaner. I still wonder, however, why `tf.get_variable()`could not find the variable. Could you explain why this is so? Thanks!

Comment: I think this actually fails because running `tf.variable_scope()` in a different thread actually refers to a different `tf.Graph` instance from the one in which you originally created the variable. If you did something like `with sess.graph.as_default(), tf.variable_scope("scope_global_step", reuse=True):` it would, but **only if you had a single training thread**. The graph isn't thread-safe for writing, and entering a variable scope causes some graph-internal data structures to be updated, so you should never do this :).

Comment: Thanks a lot again @mrry. I think I have learnt one or two important things :-)